# Arch: How to set keyboard mapping for full disk encryption with dm-crypt and LUKS

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout, luks

I try to install arch linux with full disk encryption.

After switching to my locale keyboard layout (de-latin1) I entered my password which contains several special characters.

Unfortunatelly after reboot it seems not to use my keyboard layout so LUKS tells me there is "no key available with this passphrase".

I tried to set the options in

/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf

to

```
options cryptdevice=UUID=********-****:vg0 root=/dev/mapper/vg0-root resume=/dev/mapper/vg0-swap rw intel_pstate=no_hwp lang=de-latin1 locale=de_DE.UTF-8
```

or

```
options cryptdevice=UUID=********-****:vg0 root=/dev/mapper/vg0-root resume=/dev/mapper/vg0-swap rw intel_pstate=no_hwp lang=de locale=de_DE.UTF-8
```

both did not help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

<**UUID**> is your partition UUID, not the  placeholder.

Comment: Of course... But I did not post it ;-) 
Perhaps I better use asterix for clarification...

Comment: If I had the UUID wrong arch would not even have been booted. But the error is not "arch not booting" but "arch not using the right keymapping after booting".

Comment: im not saying its the complete answer but it is part of your problem.

Comment: no it is not. Please re-read my last comments ;-) 
The Problem is NOT a wrong UUID. If I did that wrong it would not even boot. The Problem is that on booting the wrong keymap was loaded which caused troubles with unlocking the encrypted device. That was the core of my question.